# How to create a new column in Athena table from an array based on a specific key value?

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-athena, presto, trino

We use QuickSight for visualizing cost data. GCP exports a lot of their billing data fields as arrays, but AWS QuickSight can't import arrays currently. So, I am trying to create an Athena view by pulling certain values out of the arrays and putting them into their own column.

An example is the project field, which has arrays within struct:

```
struct<id:string,number:string,name:string,labels:array<struct<key:string,value:string>>,ancestry_numbers:string,ancestors:array<struct<resource_name:string,display_name:string>>>
```

The `labels` array within the above project struct has a `key: environment` with different values. I want to pull that data into a new column so that I can filter all rows by `environment` values.

I can't figure out how to create a new column based on a specific array value. The following query returns an error:

```
SELECT *
FROM "database"."table" 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(project.labels) AS t(labels)
where contains(labels.key, 'environment')
limit 10
```

```
Error: AMBIGUOUS_NAME: line 4:16: Column 'labels' is ambiguous
```

EDIT:

I am able to pull the `labels` array into a separate column with the following query:

```
SELECT "billing_account_id", labels
FROM "database"."table" 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(project.labels) as labels
ON TRUE
limit 10
```

This gives me the following table:

| billing_account_id | labels |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | [{key=environment, value=prod}] |
| 1234567891 | [{key=environment, value=dev}] |

However, this still doesn't fully solve my question as I want to create a separate column that looks like this:

| billing_account_id | environment |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | prod |
| 1234567891 | dev |

Is there a way to do this all within the same query, or do I need to create an Athena view from the first query & then run a second `UNNEST` query to create a view that will give me the second table?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As [the docs](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) say `unnest` will expand the array into single column, which you have named `labels` which matches the column name on the left side of the join (i.e. one column from the source - `"database"."table"`). You can rename the expanded column, for example into `label` (which seems more appropriate name):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "database"."table" 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(project.labels) AS t(label)
where strpos(label.key, 'environment') > 0
limit 10
```

Or use aliases:

```sql
SELECT id,
   number,
   -- s.labels if needed
   -- rest of columns from the source
   t.labels.key key,
   t.labels.value value
FROM "database"."table" s
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(project.labels) AS t(labels)
where strpos(t.labels.key, 'environment') > 0
limit 10
```

P.S.

Use [`strpos`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#strpos), `contains` is array function in Presto/Trino.

Comment: Hi, I tried the top option and am now getting this error: 

`FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND: line 4:7: Unexpected parameters (varchar, varchar(11)) for function contains. Expected: contains(varchar, ipaddress), contains(array(t), t) T:comparable` 

There is no "ipaddress" in the table so I'm not sure where that is even coming from.

Comment: @Vera yes, that code was suspicious too. Use `strpos`. See the update.